# Turn on MOSFet with Optotransistor

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I am building a pcb where I will be switching a bunch of MOSFets which are optoisolated. My plan is to do this with optotransistors.

A typical circuit for a transistor controlled MOSFet, which I'm seeing online, is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvmHDQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My concern about this circuit is that it seems to be inverting. When the input is high the MOSFet is turned off and vice versa.

Would the following circuit be a viable non-inverting replacement?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3iLgc.png)</sup>

NOTE: Transistors showing second half of optoisolators

Comment: Where's the opto?

Comment: @Andyaka I figured the opto would function identically to a transistor. So i modelled it as a transistor instead.

Comment: So just show it as a transistor with nothing connected to the base and remove references to 2N3904 and put some text onto the picture that clearly informs the reader that the transistor is one half of an opto. It's not rocket science being clear.

Comment: fair enough, will do

Comment: why does it matter what the logic that triggers the MOSFET bother you? How are your driving the LED is it active high or low? You can fix that at the LED side rather than the MOSFET side.

Comment: @DIODEX The LEDs are connected directly to the output of microcontroller pins. Therefore they are active high. I don't want to add extra transistors for each optoisolator because it will increase the amount of components unnecessarily.

I don't want the MOSFETs to be active LOW, because they will be turned on as a default, and as this is a general purpose board, i feel that Lighting and Motors turning on mistakenly is a bad idea

Comment: What switching speed must  you achieve?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Nothing fancy. 1KHz minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove R1 (replace it with a short) and it'll work fine with an optotransistor in place of Q1.

It will *not* work with a regular transistor, however, since Q1 is wired as an emitter follower and won't deliver the full gate voltage. (It will only deliver the input voltage, minus a diode drop, to the gate.)

Comment: +1 I'd increase R2 and reduce R3 also

Answer (score 1):

Since your microcontroller is driving the LEDs in the opto change the logic in your program such that you output a "low" when you want the LOAD ON as following
[image: Active Low]

If you cannot change the program then you can "switch" the ground to the LED and achieve the same:

[image]

Comment: Using the micro as a sink is a nice idea. I don't like the idea of doing it in code. if this was a purpose specific board i would, but since it's general purpose, i want the coding to be natural

Comment: Most of the time you want to sink anyways, as microcontrollers have a better spec sinking than sourcing.

Comment: Just one thing to watch out for with this configuration - at startup the MCU output may be floating (perhaps for several seconds if it runs a bootloader) and then the load will be turned ON.